# RSA2048 signature output Base64length

Tags: certificate, rsa, x509certificate, signing, sha512

I am trying to sign a text using a certificate in my personal store. I am supposed to sign it with RSA2048 and then convert the output to the BASE64 string. The output I am getting is just 172 characters. Can you help understand is better where am I making mistake? As per my understanding, the output base64 length should be more.

```
RSAParameters privateKey =  new RSAParameters();
            foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in my.Certificates)
            {
                if (cert.Subject.Contains(certSubject))
                {

                    using (var rsa = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey())
                        {
                            UnicodeEncoding encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
                            byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(text);
                            return rsa.SignData(data, HashAlgorithmName.SHA512, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
                        }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Indeed, the byte count seems to indicate RSA/1024.

Comment: The key size determines the size of the signature. Probably the key size is only 1024 bits. You can check this with `rsa.KeySize`.